# Need help in Django 2x ,( FOREIGN KEY constraint failed )

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

hi everyone i made a simple modeland my problem is when i try to make a FOREIGN KEY in my model it shows me this error message , it would be awesome if you can help 
here is the code

Model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class category(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class gigpost(models.Model):

    title=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100)
    Category=models.OneToOneField(category,on_delete=True,default='')
    published_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description=models.TextField(default='',max_length=None)
    mainphoto=models.ImageField(default='')
    photo=models.FileField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import gigpost , category

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(gigpost)
admin.site.register(category)
```

the error message :

```
IntegrityError at /admin/gigpost/category/add/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/gigpost/category/add/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Exception Location: C:\Users\Madara\Miniconda3\envs\myEv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py in _commit, line 240
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Madara\Miniconda3\envs\myEv\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Madara\\Desktop\\empliya\\empliya',
 'C:\\Users\\Madara\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myEv\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Madara\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myEv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Madara\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myEv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Madara\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myEv',
 'C:\\Users\\Madara\\Miniconda3\\envs\\myEv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 18 Feb 2020 19:34:39 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
category=models.OneToOneField(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default='')
```

instead of

```
Category=models.OneToOneField(category,on_delete=True,default='')
```

also class name should be in uppercase:

```
class Category(models.Model):
class Gigpost(models.Model):
```